# Bulk Search E-Mail Headers

Tags: php, email, imap, cpanel, pop3

I would like to find out all e-mails that have been received by our mail server from a particular IP address, contained in the Message Headers.

It is a static IP, and I have found some already by manual means, but I am trying to find a way to either do this programatically, perhaps using a PHP script with full access on my mail server, or perhaps there is a function within cPanel itself which will do this?

How would one go about searching all e-mail headers for this IP?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at procmail. It's a tool that can be used to process email messages as they arrive to your mailbox. You can specify the processing on the email message based on any field in the message header. In your case, you would be considering the "Received:" field which displays the IP address upstream email server.

Although procmail is generally used for processing email as it arrives, it is also possible to use it to process existing mail stored in mailboxes if you can cat and pipe the messages from the mailbox to procmail.

There is a simple example in the link below that explains the basics of using procmail.

[Howto filter and forward e-mail with procmail: example](http://www.codealias.info/technotes/howto_filter_e-mail_with_procmail_a_simple_example)

Comment: OK SabZee, I'll see if I can get procmail up and running and figure out how to use it! I'm also experimenting with downloading Thunderbird to my Mac, as it appears that will natively search headers too.